# get last 30 days from the date which I selected from datepicker using Calendar in android

Tags: android, datepicker

I want to get last 30 days from the date which I selected from datepicker. Can anyone suggest me the way how can I get that.

I am able to do this functionality using current date but selecting date from datepicker I can not understand how can I do this.

```
final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(new Date());
cal.roll(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -30);
Date daysBeforeDate = cal.getTime();
```

I am doing with current date using above code into **DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener.**

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the code you are currently using for the date picker?

Comment: I add my code which I am using now

Answer (score 1):

You would use code like this for instance:

```
final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener d=new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
  public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
  {
      cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
      cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
      cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
      cal.roll(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -30);
  }
};
```

Comment: Hey can you tell me If I want to check the selected date between two other date is not then can is it possible and how?